# How do I set the Firefox locale when using Selenium Grid?

Tags: firefox, selenium

How do I set the Firefox locale using a Selenium Grid installation? I can change the locale manually, but not through Selenium. Here is my code:

`

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();  
if (browserLoc != null) // Force browser to a locale independent of OS locale
{
  profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", browserLoc);
  profile.setPreference("intl.locale.matchOS", "false");
  profile.setPreference("general.useragent.locale", browserLoc);
  try
  {
    profile.addExtension(new File("C:/Downloads/francais_language_pack-31.0-fx.xpi"));
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
break;
```

...

```
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(seleniumHubURL), caps);`
```

Running this causes Firefox to start in English no matter what. The path specified is a valid path to the French XPI file, and browserLoc is set to 'fr'.

Also, when Firefox starts, I can go to about:config and observe that the preferences listed above are set as I have coded them.

How might I get firefox to start in French?